# xcode build phase run script no longer executes on xcode 15.1

Tags: xcode, react-native, shell, xcode15

I have been using the following script for a couple years with no issues (I am running this script inside xcode).

```
# Name of the resource to copy
INFO_PLIST_FILE=GoogleService-Info.plist
echo "PLIST FILE: ${INFO_PLIST_FILE}"
# Get references to debug and release versions of the plist file
DEBUG_INFO_PLIST_FILE="${PROJECT_DIR}/${TARGET_NAME}/Firebase/Debug/${INFO_PLIST_FILE}"
RELEASE_INFO_PLIST_FILE="${PROJECT_DIR}/${TARGET_NAME}/Firebase/Release/${INFO_PLIST_FILE}"

# Make sure the debug version exists
echo "Looking for ${INFO_PLIST_FILE} in ${DEBUG_INFO_PLIST_FILE}"
if [ ! -f "$DEBUG_INFO_PLIST_FILE" ] ; then
    echo "File GoogleService-Info.plist (debug) not found."
    exit 1
fi

# Make sure the release version exists
echo "Looking for ${INFO_PLIST_FILE} in ${RELEASE_INFO_PLIST_FILE}"
if [ ! -f "$RELEASE_INFO_PLIST_FILE" ] ; then
    echo "File GoogleService-Info.plist (release) not found."
    exit 1
fi

# Get a reference to the destination location for the plist file
PLIST_DESTINATION="${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app"

case "${CONFIGURATION}" in
   "Release" )
        echo "BUILD CONFIG: RELEASE"
        cp -r "$RELEASE_INFO_PLIST_FILE" "$PLIST_DESTINATION" ;;
        
   "dev.release" )
        echo "BUILD CONFIG: RELEASE DEV"
        cp -r "$RELEASE_INFO_PLIST_FILE" "$PLIST_DESTINATION" ;;

   "Debug" )
        echo "BUILD CONFIG: DEBUG"
        cp -r "$DEBUG_INFO_PLIST_FILE" "$PLIST_DESTINATION" ;;
        
   "dev.debug" )
        echo "BUILD CONFIG: DEBUG DEV"
        cp -r "$DEBUG_INFO_PLIST_FILE" "$PLIST_DESTINATION" ;;

    *)
        ;;
esac
```

I recently upgraded to an M3 mac machine / xcode 15.1, and got my app running (so i thought)

I pushed my app to the store for an update to soon realize my FCM push notifications were not working. After hours of digging for the issue, I came to the conclusion my build phase script was not running at all.

This script decides which googleinfo.plist file to use for my firebase configuration for each environment.

I have tried to re-make the script, and I also tried to move the script to the bottom of my build phases, but still no luck. I cant even echo a log from any new script i create. This script shows nothing in the logs besides

Comment: @shellter if you knew how to read you would understand I cant log anything pal.

Comment: Well, my point was that you said *"I have been using this run script ..."*  but you haven't included the script in your question. How can readers hope to help if your problem description boils down to "New gear, It stopped working"? Read about [mcve] and include details so expert readers can reproduce your problem in their home environment. It seems like a good place to start would be to document *" I cant even echo a log from any new script i create."*. So sort of a "Hello World" code will be easier to diagnose. Good luck.

Comment: Better. Does your script have an `#!/bin/bash` or other "she-bang" line at the top? Please include that. I'd also recommend adding output of `uname -srv` and the exact version number from `xcode` (From the About Menu option) and the output from `echo "PATH=$PATH"`. Are you only starting this script from inside Xcode? Can you run it from a terminal command line? What happens then? .... THEN i see a lot of `echo ...` statements. Is there output from any of those? Add `set -x` (`set +x` to disable) AND PS4='${LINENO} >'` near the top for debugging output to see what values are being used ....

Comment: for env-vars `PLIST_DESTINATION` etc, and make sure those values make sense. You may also see something obvous about what it's not working. I'm only generally familiar with Xcode build systems, so best to include any special configs used under the Configuration menu (or elsewhere). Readers still need to know how to duplicate how you are running your build, so the more you can add (as small as possible) that will let them copy/paste, the more likely you are to get help. Also, did you look at/aware of [apple.se]? This maybe a well known issue there. Good luck.

Comment: (make that `export PS4='${LINENO} >'` .)

Comment: @shellter I am running the script directly in xcode in the build phases tab. The Shell is set on xcode as `/bin/sh`. None of my echo statements show up in the console but they did before in xcode 14.